# Place an image on top of another image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

What I want to do is the following. A user can take a picture with the iPhone camera. After the picture is taking their will be another image placed on top of the taken picture. also the image that is placed on top should rotate a 25°. Besides the rotation I also need to lower that image on top a little bit below the taken picture.
You can see what I mean over here.

[image]

I have the following.

```
-(UIImage *)drawImage:(UIImage*)profileImage withBadge:(UIImage *)badge
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(profileImage.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [profileImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, profileImage.size.width, profileImage.size.height)];
    [badge drawInRect:CGRectMake(profileImage.size.width - badge.size.width, profileImage.size.height - badge.size.height,badge.size.width,badge.size.height)];

    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}

-(void)captureImage {
    UIImage *img1 = [cropFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"genkonstage.jpg"]; 
    UIImage *img = [self drawImage:img1 withBadge:img2];

    //UIImage *img = [cropFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
    [stillCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
    [stillCamera stopCameraCapture];
    [self removeAllTargets];

    staticPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:img
                                       smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
```

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Does your *drawImage:withBadge:* method do what is expected to? Seems it should be working on the task of mixing two images in one

Comment: Yes it places the image on top of the other. But I want to rotate it also. And I can't find a way to do that with a UIImage.

Comment: Yes, better to do such things (rotations etc.) with context in this case. Take a glance at my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

-(UIImage *)drawImage:(UIImage*)profileImage withBadge:(UIImage *)badge
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(profileImage.size, NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(imageContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, profileImage.size.width, profileImage.size.height));  // just in case let's clear the context
    [profileImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, profileImage.size.width, profileImage.size.height)];
    float angle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(20);
    CGContextSaveGState (imageContext); {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, profileImage.size.width - badge.size.width, profileImage.size.height - badge.size.height); // this will shift your context
        CGAffineTransform rotationMatrix = CGAffineTransformMake(cos(angle), -sin(angle), sin(angle), cos(angle), 0, 0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(imageContext, rotationMatrix); // this will rotate the context
        // Now, having the context prepared (rotated and translated), draw the badge into it
        [badge drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, badge.size.width, badge.size.height)];
    } CGContextRestoreGState (imageContext);
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

This code is working for me.

Comment: please let me know about the result so I could edit the answer for the future readers

Comment: This should work, but you could simplify the code a little bit. Instead of constructing `rotationMatrix` by hand, you could simply use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`, or even `CGContextRotateCTM`. Also, `CGContextClearRect` isn't needed in a newly-created image context (and if you were to use it nevertheless, you should pass a rectangle with the same size as the image context).

Comment: thanks, omz, good point. Just about the clearing ... I personally had the problems of 'dirty context' kind even with the newly created contexts. Perhaps it was because of some other issues, but now I'm trying to keep myself sure :)

Comment: @makaron sorry for the late reaction. I updated my code with your code. But now their is no image placed on top of the other one..

Comment: Well, as I had said before there could be some inaccuracies since I was coding from memory. I've made some crucial fixes and tested the result this time. This piece is ready to use now.