# Capture UIView and Save as Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, swift3

First of i Add the `UILable` on `UIImageView` and then after i screenshot the `UIView`, the image not proper capture the `UIView` Frame i also attach the image  url.

[image]

[1) Original Image Link:](https://postimg.cc/image/fitpypmip/)

[image]

[2) After Capture the image Link:](https://postimg.cc/image/fwn8svecd/)

Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewImage.frame.size);
[viewImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *vwImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(vwImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:imagename];
NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
[data writeToFile:strPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I think the screenshot was taken correctly. The problem I see on the other side. Are you sure, that your UIView has the same size as the source image? If no, then do you add the UIImage to your view without changing its size? Are you sure? :) 'Couse if you have an image of size 200x500, but you drew it on UIView of size 300x700 allowing UIView to stretch the image for it to occupy all the space, then you'll have a screenshot of the UIView size, not the source image

Comment: when i save that capture image in photo library at that time the date in not proper display

Comment: Ah, ok, got it now. Try to check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062974/place-an-image-on-top-of-another-image/16064804#16064804   There's a fully working code for your purpose

Comment: Answer using API with better performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display#25585958

Answer (score 28):

You can take the screenshots of any `UIView` or capture any `UIView` and save it as an image with below code.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

    //hide controls if needed
    CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

Comment: when i save that capture image in photo library at that time the date in not proper display

Comment: you try it out this method?? and also change Autoresize property of UILable

Comment: hey click on your main view and select file inspector and unchecked the Autolayout property may be its the issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31863/discussion-between-rushabh-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 15):

**Take snapshot of a UIView**

pass your view to this function it will handle everything itself( **No need to set bounds or frames**)

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height));
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: [view.layer renderInContext:ctx] solution proposed everywhere on internet was throwing CGGetColorAlpha EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but this worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Big upvote for drawViewHierarchyInRect rather than .layer renderInContext. It has better quality and in my usecase was the only one that worked, as it includes the whole hierarchy

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3 Version:

```
func takeSnapshotOfView(view:UIView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5 as extension:

```
extension UIView {

    func takeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height - 5))
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    func saveToPhotoLibrary(_ completionTarget: Any?, _ completionSelector: Selector?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self, completionTarget, completionSelector, nil)
        }
    }
}

extension UIAlertController {

    func present() {
        guard let controller = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        controller.present(self, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In your `UIView` sub class:

```
func saveImage() {
    let selector = #selector(self.onImageSaved(_:error:contextInfo:))
    takeSnapshot()?.saveToPhotoLibrary(self, selector)
}

@objc private func onImageSaved(_ image: UIImage, error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        ac.present()
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        ac.present()
    }
    onImageSaved?()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below code to

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pictureView.bounds.size);                      
[pictureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, viewImage.frame);     

[viewImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *vwImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(vwImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:imagename];
NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
[data writeToFile:strPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want captured image maintain its original quality.

```
- (UIImage *)captureViewWithAllSubView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return capturedImage;
}
```