# Share image with text in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am making an photo editing app in which I have applied some photo editing effect on selected image and then save image. After that when user press on share button I select image form photo gallery and share it on facebook, whatsapp, wechat, googleplus, instagram etc. Now problem is that I want share image with message.

Comment: this question needs more detail:  share your image *how* (SMS, e-mail, posting it to Facebook or via some web server).  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by share image with text? It very vague what that means. Please provide more detail of you requirements and code.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I want to share on any social app just like whatsapp, instagram, wechat, message, mail, googleplus, facebook.

Comment: @Popeye My app is photo editing app in which we do some graphical work on selected photo and save it. Then we select our saved photo from photo library and share it on facebook.

Comment: @user3305573 Ok that answers the question of the word "Share" now what do you mean by with text? Is the text on the image? Inline with the Image? Just on the same message? Also please update your question and don't leave a comment with the new information as people don't read comments they read questions, and again what code have you got? Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I guess, you have a common image on which text is different. Adding this different text, you'll share this image. Right?
If this is the problem, set the image on uiview and set the uilabel on it. after setting the uilabel, take the screenshot of only uiview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text to an image then load the image in a UIImageView then add a UILabel as a subview.  Then render the views into an UIImage. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145049/capture-uiview-and-save-as-image)

Then to share the image use UIActivityViewController [like this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/)