# Add a text to an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an UIImage I want to allow the user to circle a particular part of the image and then write something about it on the image and then I want to save this image.

I do not know how to start on this are there any libraries or example that can help

Answer (score 0):

First take one UIImageView add your image in it. Now add label as subview in UIImageView.
Now finally capture the the UIView as image.
Here this will help you to code for capture the UIView as image
Thanks.
[Capture UIView and Save as Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145049/capture-uiview-and-save-as-image)